# Custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken is not getting called. How do I get the token handler registered and called?

Tags: wcf, wif

Based on the MSDN documentation I have created a custom UserNameSecurityTokenHandler and put in the CanValidateToken override and ValidateToken override.  I thought I had configured the WCF web service to use the custom handler but the ValdiateToken never gets called.  Here is the custom token handler:

```
public class CustomUserNameSecurityTokenHandler : UserNameSecurityTokenHandler 
{
    public override bool CanValidateToken
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity> ValidateToken(SecurityToken token)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();

        if (token == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        }
        var userNameToken = token as UserNameSecurityToken;
        if (userNameToken == null)
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");
        }

        if ( userNameToken.UserName != userNameToken.Password )
        {
            throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid username or password.");
        }
        var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, userNameToken.UserName),
                new Claim(
                    "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/ClaimTypes.AuthenticationInstant",
                    XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime.UtcNow, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"),
                    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime")
            };

        return new ReadOnlyCollection<ClaimsIdentity>(new List<ClaimsIdentity> {new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Password")});
    }
}
```

The debugger does not launch.  The client code always fails when I call it.
Here is my WCF web.config entries for the site:

```
 <configSections>
 <section name="system.identityModel" type="System.IdentityModel.Configuration.SystemIdentityModelSection, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</configSections>
<appSettings>
  <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfUserName.Service1">
      <endpoint address="Service1.svc" binding="netHttpBinding"
        contract="WcfUserName.IService1" />
      <host>
        <baseAddresses>
          <add baseAddress="https://localhost/WcfUserName" />
        </baseAddresses>
      </host>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <netHttpBinding>
      <binding>
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </netHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceCredentials useIdentityConfiguration="true" />
        <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="Always"/>
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      </behavior>
     </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
 <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="netHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
 </protocolMapping>    
 <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
 <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
 </system.webServer>
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration name="identconfig">
    <securityTokenHandlers>
      <remove type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.WindowsUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, System.IdentityModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add type="WcfUserName.Security.CustomUserNameSecurityTokenHandler, WcfUserName"/>
    </securityTokenHandlers>
  </identityConfiguration>
 </system.identityModel>
```

I assume something is wrong with my configuration but cannot tell what it is.  Any ideas?

Comment: When I watch the traffic I can see the username and password in the SOAP envelop, but I am getting a 500 - 'At least one security token in the message could not be validated.'  back, while my validator is not getting called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to configure this correctly in web.config.  This means you need to add you securitytokenhandler, but also remove the default username password handler.  So you need to either  <remove > the previous handler, or start over and <clear> the collection of securitytokenhandlers in the configuration file.